# How to decode such messages?

Tags: matrices

In the Matrix encryption method we transform message into matrix and encrypt it by pre-multiplying it with some encoding matrix.
The decoding is based on the fact that the inverse of decoding matrix can bring back the original message as they cancel out.
But what if the encoding matrix is singular ie. Its Inverse does not exist.
Then how will we find the original message Would it be possible to decode the message.

Comment: Euler's real dad would have known the answer without actually asking it online.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I am not like my son but i am proud of him

Comment: @mvw i couldn't understand please clarify, Son

Comment: I was looking for an example of matrix decoding and found only references to audio methods, but now I found a link on Hill ciphers. :-)

Comment: @mvm Ok son, May god bless you

Answer (score 0):

In general, if an encryption method is represented by a function $f$ mapping source messages to encrypted messages, it's decodable if and only if $f$ is injective. Otherwise, if both $f(x_1)=y$ and $f(x_2)=y$, it's not possible to decode the message $y$ even in principle, since either $x_1$ or $x_2$ could have generated it.

In your case, if $A$ is a singular matrix, then it cannot be injective, so there is no way of decoding the corresponding message.

Comment: That means it is hashing technique

Comment: @Euler'sDad Sure, but with a potentially high chance of collisions.